# Ordering and getting data from custom List - C#

Tags: c#, list, .net-3.5

I have a custom list I created which contains a full folder path and a corresponding version number. I store both of these values in a list. I want to them get the highest X versions and their corresponding folder paths as stored in the list. I've struggled with this for a while but now it's time for help. The code I've got so far is as follows:

This is my list class:

```
class versionFolder
{
    public int version { get; set; }
    public string folderDIR { get; set; }

    public versionFolder(int version, string folderDIR)
    {
        this.version = version;
        this.folderDIR = folderDIR;
    }

}
```

Here is my code for creating the list and adding items to it. At the bottom I want to print out the contents of the list (versions and folder paths of said versions) then right at the bottom I want to get the highest X versions as set by the depth variable.

```
    public highestVersion(string dsPath, int depth)
    {
        int num = depth;
        List<versionFolder> allVersions = new List<versionFolder>(); //list to hold all version numbers and full path

        string folder = dsPath;
        string[] versionDIRS = Directory.GetDirectories(folder);

        foreach (string folderr in versionDIRS)
        {
            string[] fullpath = folderr.Split('\\');

            string folderName = fullpath[fullpath.Length - 1]; //returns VXX-XXXXXXXX (version folder name)
            string vString = "6"; //sets a version number, this is actually data extrapolated from the folder path
            allVersions.Add(new versionFolder(Convert.ToInt32(vString), fullpath.ToString()));
        }



        foreach (var version in allVersions)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Amount is {0}", version.version);
            Console.WriteLine("Amount is {0}", folderDIR.folderDIR);
        }
        var testtt = allVersions.OrderByDescending(n => n.version).Take(Convert.ToInt32(num));
        Console.Write("Test:" + testtt);
    }
```

The output is fine for the versions number but I can't get the folderDIR's.
The output for getting the highest X values returns this:

```
Test:System.Linq.Enumerable+<TakeIterator>d__3a`1[Importer.versionFolder]
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I thought it might be worth noting that I'm having to use .NET 3.5

Comment: At : allVersions.Add(new versionFolder(Convert.ToInt32(vString), fullpath.ToString())); you are converting fullpath string array to string. But actual  versionFolder's folderDir is in string not string array format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Take()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb503062(v=vs.100).aspx) method returns type is `IEnumerable`,if you want to get return type `List<T>`, just call `ToList()` method. If you want to get `foldDir` field only, then call `Select` method would work.

```
    public IList<string> HighestVersion(int topCount)
    {
        List<VersionFolder> vfList = new List<VersionFolder>
       {
           new VersionFolder(1, "A"),
           new VersionFolder(4, "B"),
           new VersionFolder(3, "C")
       };

        vfList = vfList.OrderBy(v => v.Version).Take(topCount).ToList();

        foreach (VersionFolder versionFolder in vfList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(versionFolder.FolderDir);
        }

        //return folderDir only
        return vfList.Select(v=>v.FolderDir).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It is working in the sense that it gets the top X values however the output is:

    System.String[]
    System.String[]
    System.String[].

I am guessing it's because versionFolder.FolderDIR is an array? Sorry, I'm a little new to this. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SteveMaybes Sorry, I missed you've another problem, this is caused by this line `allVersions.Add(new versionFolder(Convert.ToInt32(vString), fullpath.ToString()));`,  `fullpath` is an array, if you want to convert it to string, use `string.Join(",", fullpath)` instead of `fullpath.ToString()`.